# Epplus exception whist saving

Tags: excel, vb.net, epplus

I keep getting the following error message when I try to edit an existing excel file:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." & vbCrLf & "Parameter name: index

Code:

```
Dim file As New FileInfo(Path)
Dim objXLApp = New ExcelPackage(file)

Dim objXLWs = objXLApp.Workbook.Worksheets("DiscreteAlarms")
Dim aantal_Rows As Integer = objXLWs.Dimension.Rows
pgb_alarm_check_File2.Maximum = aantal_Rows
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To aantal_Rows
    Dim Alarm_Text = objXLWs.Cells(i, 3).Value
    If Alarm_Text = "" Then
        objXLWs.Cells(i, 3).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red)
    End If
    pgb_alarm_check_File2.Value = i
Next
objXLApp.Save()
```

Comment: You should debug with try-catch blocks

Comment: this is the try code i debugged with a break point on the save action. and the exception is thrown on the save action

Comment: What is `pgb_alarm_check_File2`?

Comment: a progress bar but that is not the problem i already commented out every thing. the exception is thrown on the save action of the epplus module

Comment: I have tested your code and had a slight issue which wasn't linked to the error. I had to add `objXLWs.Cells(i, 3).Style.Fill.PatternType = Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid` prior to you setting the `BackgroundColour`. The only other thing that will be different is the spreadsheet itself. The error _Index was out of range._ suggests something to do with the `For i` statement rather than the saving. Wrap the `For i` statement in a `Try Catch` and see if it catches. Sometimes debuggers stop on the line after the exception which can lead to confusion. Also you can remove `Dim i As Integer`

Comment: Thanks I used an excel generated from another programm and there seem to be something wrong there. tested it with a new excel file and works